# Problems with CamelCase and underscore Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models with a has many through association between them like below:

```
TipoDocumento < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :dependencias
    has_many :TipoRequisitos, :through => :dependencias
    ...
end

TipoRequisito < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :dependencias
    has_many :TipoDocumentos, :through => :dependencias
    ...
end

Dependencia < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to: TipoDocumento
    belongs_to: TipoRequisito
    ...
end
```

The id's attributes for the join model Dependencia are TipoDocumento_id and TipoRequisito_id.

Now, when I try this in the rails console:

```
x = TipoDocumento.find(1)
x.TipoRequisitos
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: dependencia.tipo_documento_id: SELECT "tipo_requisitos".* FROM "tipo_requisitos" INNER JOIN "dependencia" ON "tipo_requisitos"."id" = "dependencia"."TipoRequisito_id" WHERE "dependencia"."tipo_documento_id" = 1
```

also if I try the opposite with TipoRequisito it's the same.

It seems that Rails is changing somehow the TipoDocumento_id column name for tipo_documento_id when it performs the query. So, I tried to change the id's column's names from their CamelCase to their snake_case, but I get the analog error (Cannot find TipoDocumento_id or TipoRequisito_id.)

I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: You are not following the rails convention, so you need to specify the names of the columns.

Comment: What do I have to change for following the convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow the Rails convention and use down-cased names when you refer to models when defining relations:

```
 TipoDocumento < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :dependencias
     has_many :tipo_requisitos, through: :dependencias
     ...
 end

 TipoRequisito < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :dependencias
     has_many :tipo_documentos, :through => :dependencias
     ...
 end

Dependencia < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tipo_documento
    belongs_to :tipo_requisito
    ...
 end
```

you need to lower-case it, like this:

```
  x = TipoDocumento.find(1)
  x.tipo_requisitos
```

Please also check: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: That worked! I tried that once but forgot to change the camelcase on the Dependencia model. Thank you